# Регулярное выражение для поиска строки между ограничителями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Помогите разобраться с регулярным выражением.

Есть строка:

```
тут что то \n <Начало> вывести этот текст <Конец> и \n тут что то тоже;
```

Как правильно задать условие, что бы после `<начало>` и до `<конец>` вывело текст? 
Вот мое условие:

```
var SomeText = 'тут что то \n <Начало> вывести этот текст <Конец> и \n тут что то тоже';
var re = /<Начало>.*<Конец>/gm;
var Result = re.exec(SomeText); //<Начало> вывести этот текст <Конец>
```

Выводит вместе с `<Начало>` и `<Конец>`. Я делал разные варианты, удавалось только убрать  `<Конец>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Начало>(.*?)<Конец>
```

вот так же

Comment: `"?" = "{0,1}"`

Там звездочка должна быть (`"*" = "{0,}"`)

Comment: @Sh4dow, тов. @Scipetr всё правильно написал, это не жадный поиск.

Comment: ай тьфу, я увидел ".?", пардон

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, как в javascript, но попробуйте так:

```
/<Начало>(.*)<Конец>/gm;
```

В скобочках - это маска, и я хз вообще, как к ней в js обратиться. )

Comment: А эти скобочки будут как условие после? Или то что в скобочках?

Comment: Через .group(1)

Comment: Нашел, Result[1] = вывести этот текст.

Answer (score -1):

По-моему так :

```
var SomeText = 'тут что то \n <Начало> вывести этот текст <Конец> и \n тут что то тоже';
var re = /<Начало>.*<Конец>/gm;
var Result = SomeText.exec(re); //<Начало> вывести этот текст <Конец>
```

точно знать не могу, но попробуйте.

Comment: Вы до конца вопрос прочтите :)

Answer (score -1):

***Вот все работает:***

```
    var SomeText = 'тут что то \n <Начало> вывести этот текст <Конец> и \n тут что то тоже',
    start = SomeText.search(/<Начало>/gi)+8,
    end = SomeText.search(/<Конец>/gi),
    solve = SomeText.slice(start,end);
    alert(solve);
```

//или так

```
alert(SomeText.slice(SomeText.search(/<Начало>/gi)+8,SomeText.search(/<Конец>/gi)));
```