# Регулярное выражение для части URL

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Исходная строка:

```
/catalog/personalcase/apple/filter/manufacturer/kollektia/apply/
```

Как получить все, что после `/filter/` и до `/apply/` виде массива?

Вот пример:

```
Array
(
    [0] => manufacturer/kollektia
)
```

Comment: сделал так ([^/]+?)/filter/(.+?)/apply/ или есть проще вариант?

Comment: норм, только результат во второй группе, а не нулевой

Comment: Перенесите свое решение в ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение для поска строки между ограничителями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26678/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: @VenZell зачем в ответ когда это решение относится к вопросу как испробованный вариант?

Comment: Что должны получить в случе если исходная строка будет выглядеть как `/catalog/personalcase/apple/filter/filter/manufacturer/kollektia/apply/apply/`

Comment: @webDev_ затем, что это рабочий вариант. Пользователь спустя час после того, как задал вопрос, нашел решение самостоятельно и спрашивает есть ли более простой вариант.

Comment: @VenZell рабочие варианты выкладывают и в других вопросах и спрашивают как можно сделать проще, тот же вопрос и здесь стоит. этот рабочий вариант как его попытка а не ответ который он хочет получить на вопрос

Answer (score 0):

ответ из комментария:

---

сделал так:

```
([^/]+?)/filter/(.+?)/apply/
```